# Python 2.7 plotting query

Tags: python

Bit of a newbie question here. 
I've plotted some data in Python and I need to know where, on the x axis, the first time the corresponding y-values drop below a certain number. I want to ignore any further increases in y values.

I've tried using a zip function like:

```
for x_val, y_val in zip(xvalues, yvalues):
    if 100 < y_val < 150:
    edge1 = x_val
```

￼
But I can't seem to get my threshold values right and I would like a technique that just selects the first time the y values drop below a certain number.

Thanks.
Helen

Comment: Have you tried adding a `break` at the end of the `if` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the Y value is below the threshold you have to `break` from the loop, otherwise the loop will continue and the X value will get overwritten if the Y value is below the threshold another time.

```
for x_val, y_val in zip(xvalues, yvalues):
    if 100 < y_val < 150:
        edge1 = x_val
        break
```

Or you could use `itertools.dropwhile` to skip all the values not in that range:

```
next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda t: not 100 < t[1] < 150, zip(xvalues, yvalues)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for x_val, y_val in zip(xvalues, yvalues):
    if 100 < y_val < 150:
        edge1 = x_val
```

Your code doesn't work because the statement inside the if is not executed because it is not properly indented 
or
if you want to all the `x_val` which satisfies the the if statement

```
x=[]
for x_val, y_val in zip(xvalues, yvalues):
    if 100 < y_val < 150:
        x.append(x_val)
```